# How do I list out the column names and field types of an existing table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Assume: 
The app name is "demo2"
The model was made off of a scaffold generation ("post")

Extra specifics in regards to which sub-folder I need to change to on the command line would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do: `Post.columns` and then iterate on the resulting Array.

See more methods at [Class: ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-column_names)

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.columns.each do |column|
  puts "name: #{column.name}, type: #{column.type}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in rails 4 its:

```
Post.column_names # => ["id", "title", ... ]
```